# Multiple instances of a component shouldn't share state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Say I had a simple inputfieldcomponent like so:

```
import React, {PropTypes, PureComponent} from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import updateInput from '../../actions/inputActions';

require('./SimpleInput.sass');

export class SimpleInput extends PureComponent {
    constructor(props, context) {
         super(props, context);
    }

    handleChange (event) {
        this.props.updateField(event.target.value);
    }

    renderField () {
        return (
            <input type="text" value={this.props.value || ''} onChange={this::this.handleChange} placeholder={this.props.initial_value}/>
        )
    }

    render () {
        return(
            <span>
                {this.renderField()}
            </span>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {value: state.value.value}
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        updateInput: (value) => dispatch(updateInput(value))
    };
};

AddressInput.propTypes = {
    initial_value: PropTypes.string
};

AddressInput.defaultProps = {
    initial_value: "What's the value?"
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SimpleInput);
```

I then render two instances:

```
</SimpleInput initial_value='blah'/>
</SimpleInput>
```

However, when this is rendered, any update to one of the two fields updates both of them (due to redux only allowing for a single state).

What is the canonical way to approach this problem?

Comment: Don't put state that should not be shared in Redux. Redux should be used for state that other parts of the app need to know about. If you must do this, associate a unique identifier with each instance of the component (aka transient state).

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach Abraham and giving an example to what Dan commented on. [Check out this jsBin](https://jsbin.com/viqiqugaca/1/edit?js,console,output) demonstrating the concept of a component (here it's SimpleInput) keeping its own internal state (such as a default placeholder) while still interacting with a Container (listening to onChange). While the example doesn't use Redux (for simplicity of creating the demo) you could easily substitute onChange handles with action dispatchers.

```
class SimpleInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      defaultPlaceholder: 'Default Placeholder'
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <input 
        value={this.props.value} 
        placeholder={this.props.placeholder || this.state.defaultPlaceholder}
        onChange={this.props.onChange || ()=>{} }
      />
    )
  }

}

class SimpleInputContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.changeInput1 = this.changeInput1.bind(this);
    this.changeInput2 = this.changeInput2.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      input1: 'foo',
      input2: 'bar',
    }
  }

  changeInput1(e) {
    this.setState({
      input1: e.target.value
    })
    console.log(this.state);
  }

  changeInput2(e) {
    this.setState({
      input2: e.target.value
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SimpleInput value={this.state.input1} onChange={this.changeInput1} />
        <br />
        <SimpleInput value={this.state.input2} onChange={this.changeInput2} />
        <br />
        <SimpleInput />
        <br />
        <SimpleInput placeholder={'Explicit Placeholder'} />
      </div>
      );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<SimpleInputContainer />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

One of my use cases was an address lookup with an input managing it's value internally (no redux) and a lookup button emitting the value of the input via onClick={this.props.onSave} and in the Container handling all side effects/redux actions etc.

Lastly in your demo code, you're rerendering SimpleInput unnecessarily, which looks like a code smell. Hope that helps.